# Magento 2.2 Add Masonry JS

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, javascript, requirejs

I've a problem to include Masonry JS to my Magento 2.2

I've a custom theme in app/design/frontend/CustomVendor/CustomTheme
In this folder I've a web/ folder and inside I've requirejs-config.js

```
var config = {

    map: {
        '*': {
            'masonry' : 'js/masonry.pkgd.min'
        }
    },

    deps: [
        "js/custom-masonry"
    ]

};
```

In this same folder I've js/ folder. Inside I've custom-masonry.j

```
require([
    'jquery',
    'masonry',
    'domReady'
], function ($, domReady, masonry) {

    console.log("custom-masonry.js");

    domReady(function() {

        console.log("domReady");

        $('.contents-items').masonry({
            columnWidth: 200,
            itemSelector: '.content-items'
        });

    });

});
```

Console show me that
[image]
I think the problem is when jQuery is loaded and it's loaded before my Masonry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please move 'domReady' before 'masonry' in require or update you js with following.

```
require([
    'jquery',
    'domReady',
    'masonry'
], function ($, domReady, Masonry) {
 domReady(function() {
     console.log("domReady");
        var elem = document.querySelector('.contents-items');
         var msnry = new Masonry( elem, {
                itemSelector: '.content-item'
         });

    });

});
```

Comment: Done, but now I've a other error -> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).masonry is not a function

Comment: Please try my updated ans

Answer (score 2):

Aasim's answer looks to be correct as you need to use the vanilla JS method, if not then this is how I got it working.

I implemented it so it can easily be reused in other templates just by passing the parent and child through in the `x-magento-init` script.

**Require Config**

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            masonry: 'js/vendor/masonry/masonry.min',
            masonryInit: 'js/masonry-init',
        }
    }
};
```

**masonry-init.js**

```
define(['jquery', 'masonry', 'domReady!'], function($, Masonry) {
    return function(config) {
        var brandsLayout = {
            init: function() {
                this.initMasonry();
            },

            initMasonry: function() {
                var msnry = new Masonry( config.masonryParent, {
                    columnWidth: config.masonryChild,
                    itemSelector: config.masonryChild,
                    horizontalOrder: true,
                    percentPosition: true
                });
            }
        };

        brandsLayout.init();
    };
});
```

**And in my PHTML template**

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        ".brands-page": {
            "masonryInit": {
                "masonryParent": ".brands-page__brands",
                "masonryChild": ".brands-page__collection"
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Note I use `domReady!` with an exclamation mark so I don't have to use the `domReady()` function.